# Require statement not part of import statement.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires importing typescript from storage

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, eslint

I have to import a typescript file from the Firebase storage bucket. It contains data as well as type definitions.

```
export interface MyData {
 // ...
}

export const myData = {
 // ...
}
```

Here is the code I came with:

```js
export const readData = async (fileDir: string, fileName: string): Promise<object> => {
  // Open the bucket
  const bucket: Bucket = admin.storage().bucket()
  // Define the file path in the bucket
  const filePath: string = path.join(fileDir, fileName)
  // Define the local file path on the cloud function's server
  const tempFilePath: string = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName)
  // Download the file from the bucket
  try {
    await bucket.file(filePath).download({ destination: tempFilePath })
  } catch (error) {
    functions.logger.error(error, { structuredData: true })
  }
  // Extract the needed variable export from the file
  const data = require(tempFilePath)
  // provide the variable
  return data
}
```

eslint complain about:

> Require statement not part of import statement.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires

On:

```
const data = require(tempFilePath)
```

What would be the right way to import the file?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The eslint error message contains the error code "typescript-eslint/no-var-requires".  Doing a web search for that string comes up with the [documentation](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-var-requires.md):

> Disallows the use of require statements except in import statements
> (no-var-requires)
>
> In other words, the use of forms such as `var foo = require("foo")` are
> banned. Instead use ES6 style imports or `import foo = require("foo")`
> imports.

You will have to either relax your eslint rules to avoid this message (not recommended), or accept its suggestion and change the syntax of your code to use `import`.

If you're using TypeScript, you should read the documentation for [dynamic imports](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#dynamic-import-expressions) available with the `import()` function.

Comment: Thanks, const data = await import(tempFilePath) works nicely.

Comment: Similar issue that I was facing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66179935/how-to-resolve-typescript-eslint-no-var-requires-error-error-while-adding-axe
(Includes solution)