# How to resolve @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires error. Error while adding @axe-core/react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, accessibility

I have added axe-core/react into my project by:

```
npm install --save-dev @axe-core/react
```

Now I have added the following piece of code in my index.tsx to get it up and running:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    const axe = require('@axe-core/react');
    axe(React, ReactDOM, 1000);
}
```

Now if I navigate to localhost, the page shows a compile error with the following message:

> src\index.tsx
> Line 14:17:  Require statement not part of import statement
> @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires

This error is happening for line:

```
const axe = require('@axe-core/react');
```

How do I import it otherwise?

PS: I tried doing something like:

```
import foo = require("foo")
```

But still no luck.

Comment: Just disable the eslint rule for that line and you are good to go

Comment: I wish it was that easy....That's part of the enterprise project and unfortunately I can't do that,

Comment: Have you tried `const axe = await import('@axe-core/react');`

Comment: Good suggestion but Await won't work for me since I can't make it Async.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64016504/3825777

Comment: I had seen that link. As I had mentioned in the question, import foo = require("foo") didn't work for me. I just posted what worked for me. Thanks everyone for your suggestions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replacing the line

```
const axe = require('@axe-core/react');
```

With

```
import axe from '@axe-core/react';
```

resolved my issue.

Comment: Just be sure to check your final bundle -- axe is pretty big and it could slip in easy