# Require statement not part of import statement - google could functions and typescript

Tags: firebase, types, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

I am following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a) about using google cloud tasks to trigger a cloud function. However I am unable to upload the code because i get thrown this error. "Require statement not part of import statement" and it references this code:

```
const {CloudTasksClient} = require("@google-cloud/tasks");
```

Ive tried multiple different resolves such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59278151/eslint-require-statement-not-part-of-import-statement-typescript-eslint-no-va) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64016413/require-statement-not-part-of-import-statement-eslinttypescript-eslint-no-var-r). I am following the code and instructions exactly with no success. Does anybody have any suggestions for fixing this or another way of importing google cloud tasks? Any help would be great!

Edit:

I have tried`import {CloudTasksClient} from "@google-cloud/tasks"` and it throws back errors at my variables such as

> (Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"POST" | HttpMethod | "HTTP_METHOD_UNSPECIFIED" | "GET" | "HEAD" | "PUT" | "DELETE" | "PATCH" | "OPTIONS" | null | undefined'.)

here is my packages.json file:

```
    {
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/tasks": "^2.3.6",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.6.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.15.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.8.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `import {CloudTasksClient} from "@google-cloud/tasks"`? Which language are you using in Cloud functions? Javascript or Typescript?

Comment: What's your packages.json file? Can you share it?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I have tried that, and it pulls up a bunch of errors in the code, ill attach them to my question. I am using typescript

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Ive attached my packages.json file for you!

Comment: look into this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68797822/require-statement-not-part-of-import-statement-google-could-functions-and-type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look into this documentation and change accordingly
https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-var-requires.md